# stop next-track from removing previous track from playlist

Tags: mpd

I know this is possible because I did it before, I just cant remember how I did it. In my virtualbox when I press > in ncmpcpp it just goes to the next song in the playlist but in the fresh server I just set up pressing > removes the currently playing song from the playlist and goes to the next song.

Answer (score 0):

consume mode is toggeled by pressing Shift + R